# memory allocation and deallocation of struct c++

Tags: c++

```
struct SAD_tables
{
    typedef int** sadTable;
    sadTable sadTables[16];
    int height;
    int width;

    SAD_tables(int _height, int _width)
    {
        height = _height;
        width = _width;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            sadTables[i] = new int*[height];
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                sadTables[i][j] = new int[width];
            }
        }
    }

    ~SAD_tables()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                delete sadTables[i][j];
            }
            delete[] sadTables[i];
        }
    }
};
```

i'm not sure if i have implemented my delete function correctly. can you please explain if i'm using delete[] and delete correctly?

Comment: What does Valgrind tell you?

Comment: I recommend switching from an `int **` to a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or some `Matrix` class wrapper of that.

Comment: the overhead is too big i might use std::array but thanks anyway

Comment: are you sure the overhead of a vector compared to an int array is too much - a vector will give you a contiguous array of ints. The trick is to reserve the space first rather than let it grow as needed, in this case. At least try using a vector of int arrays rather than an array of arrays, especially if its confusing you.

Comment: Overhead? In gcc, a std::vector<> has 3 pointers: begin, end, and end of capacity plus an allocator. Are you sure your requirements are so tight you can't afford 16 bytes?

Comment: I would worry more about the fact that copying or assigning `SAD_tables` will end in disaster.

Comment: i was referring to the runtime overhead. the matrix inside this are very large. but thanks again i will check it out once more with intel parallel studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on handling memory manually instead of using a proper container class, you need to fix new/delete. Each `new` call you have is in the array form `new ...[]` so each `delete` should be `delete[]`, but you use `delete` without `[]` in the loop.